# fetch will not dispatch if I getState first

Tags: redux

I changed the signature of an action creator to make a call to `getState` before trying to dispatch fetch, but now fetch is not getting called.

**StartingPoint:** I have an async action that makes an api call using fetch and then dispatches a success or error action once it's done, as below. I call this action from a container like so  and it works fine:
  `dispatch(actions.getData());` //from a container

```
export function getData(){
  return (dispatch : any) => {
   return fetch(
      'http://localhost:8000/api',{}
    ).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      json => dispatch(successAction(json)),
      err => dispatch(notify("SERVER_ERROR"))
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need to call `getState` in the action, so that I can have an option about which port to query. Therefore, I changed the getData action to what you see below. However, when I call the action creator like this `dispatch(actions.getData());`, it's not making a network call, although the `console.log` statement is running.

Question: how can the `getData` function be written to allow for making a call to `getState` before running the fetch? (and, related, what is the purpose of wrapping it in the dispatch return)?

```
export const getData = () => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  let state = getState();
  let url = //code omitted - getting port from state object
  console.log("this log statement runs");
  return (dispatch : any) => {
   return fetch(
      url,{}
    ).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      json => dispatch(successAction(json)),
      err => dispatch(notify("SERVER_ERROR"))
    );
  }
}
```

**added Promise support**

```
   const addPromiseSupportToDispatch = (store: any) => {
      const rawDispatch = store.dispatch;
        return (action: any) => {
          if (typeof action.then === 'function') {
            return action.then(rawDispatch);
          }
          return rawDispatch(action);
        };
    };
    store.dispatch = addPromiseSupportToDispatch(store);
```

Comment: You using `redux-thunk` right?

Comment: @Ematipico yes I am. I updated the OP too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inserted an additional `return` I think. This should be the right code block

```
export const getData = () => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  let state = getState();
  let url = //code omitted - getting port from state object
  console.log("this log statement runs");
   return fetch(
      url,{}
    ).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      json => dispatch(successAction(json)),
      err => dispatch(notify("SERVER_ERROR"))
    );
}
```

EDIT

If I had to use your original code:

```
export function getData(){
  return (dispatch : any, getState: any) => { // <= second parameter provided by redux-thunk
   let url = getState().url; //can call getState here
   return fetch(
      'http://localhost:8000/api',{}
    ).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      json => dispatch(successAction(json)),
      err => dispatch(notify("SERVER_ERROR"))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why my original code works fine (see top of OP) which has the fetch wrapped in a dispatch (until I rewrite it to make a call to getState)?  I copied the pattern from the login function by Dan Abramov here https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/291#issuecomment-122829159.

Comment: What you did at beginning works fine as stated. What you needed to do, from your original code, was to add an additional parameter `getState` which is provided by default from `redux-thunk`. I think it was just a typo or a distraction error

Comment: O.k, thank you so much. I accepted your answer (and clarified where to call getState with my suggested edit). however, it's not clear to me why, in one calls, the fetch is wrapped in a return dispatch, and not in the other case

Comment: It's because you have a double return! when you do `=> (dispatch: any, getState: any)` you are implicitly returning a function, so you don't need a second `return (dispatch: any)` that was in your wrong code